# How to stop mediaPlayer when back button is pressed or other audio button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm having a problem with android programming. I want to tell you about the problem. I have a few buttons. The player is running when we click on them. But the sound does not play after the previous sound has ended.
Also, when we press the back button, it waits for the sound to end and then performs the function of the back button.

I added onBackPressed and onPause. But the program failed after the first audio play.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class officeSounds extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageButton sofitukker,millieturner,jacobbanks,jameshersey;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //fullscreen - start
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //fullscreen - end
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_office_sounds);

        sofitukker=findViewById(R.id.sofitukker);
        sofitukker.setOnClickListener(this);
        millieturner=findViewById(R.id.millieturner);
        millieturner.setOnClickListener(this);
        jacobbanks=findViewById(R.id.jacobbanks);
        jacobbanks.setOnClickListener(this);
        jameshersey=findViewById(R.id.jameshersey);
        jameshersey.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.sofitukker:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sofitukkersound);
                break;
            case R.id.millieturner:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.millieturnersound);
                break;
            case R.id.jacobbanks:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jacobbankssound);
                break;
            case R.id.jameshersey:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jamesherseysound);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mp.start();
        while (mp.isPlaying()) {
        }
        mp.release();

    }
}
```

I want to stop the previous sound when the back button and a different sound are switched.

**Edit:**
When I added switch-case statement to
`while (mp.isPlaying()) {   //here     }`

The application does not expect the sound to end. Combines sounds. When the second sound is pressed after the first sound is pressed, the second sound is played before pressing the first sound. So the two sounds are playing together for a while.

Comment: use  **`mp.stop()`** for stopping audio. 
 use **`mp.release()`**  only when you don't need MediaPlayer instance anymore, for example use  mp.release() in your activity's `onDestroy `  lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding mp.release()  each time you click on screen, so the playing media is automatically released:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    mp.release();
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.sofitukker:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sofitukkersound);
            break;
        case R.id.millieturner:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.millieturnersound);
            break;
        case R.id.jacobbanks:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jacobbankssound);
            break;
        case R.id.jameshersey:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jamesherseysound);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
```

And add this on back pressed method (or prefer mp.stop() if you don't need to keep mp ):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
mp.release();
}
```

[MediaPlayer Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#release())

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get a result as I wanted when I add mp.release() to top of switch-case statement. And also I got a keep stopping error. 

onBackPressed is working with super.onBackPressed(); and this.finish(); but mp is not stopping. Even though I tried the mp.pause, mp.release or mp.stop.